# Compiling Android with mmm and make snod

Tags: android, makefile

A complete AOSP build lasts approximately 5 hours on my laptop. Instead of running `make` after each change (just want to test some ideas...) I read that it is possible to do `mmm frameworks/opt/telephony` (or any other module) and run `make snod` afterwards.

Unfortunately this does not work for me. The emulator simply hangs during the boot while displaying the big Android letters.

Can someone give me a hint what is going on there and how to fix the problem?

It is about Android 5 on x86_64.

Comment: for solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135844/building-separate-android-modules-with-dexpreopt-disabled

Answer (score 2):

After `mmm frameworks/opt/telephony`, try running:

```
adb root
adb remount
adb sync system
```

This should only sync files you've built. Once it finishes, restart the runtime:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell start
```

Comment: Also there's `mmp` shortcut to push generated module to device

Comment: Mixaz, I don't see mmp available out of the box in AOSP. Is it cyanogen specific?

Comment: ejboy, seems so, I heard that CM envsetup differs quite a bit from default AOSP one...